# PostgreSQL Order By SubQuery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have this database structure:

### Tables:

**Category**

```
id    | category    
1     | fruit      
2     | cars       
3     | tables
```

**Product**

```
id    | product     | category_id
1     | banana      | 1
2     | apple       | 1
3     | orange      | 1
4     | example 1   | 2
5     | example 2   | 3
```

**User_List**

```
id    | product_id  | user_id | bought_date
1     | 1           | 1       | 2012-06-21 11:00:00
2     | 2           | 1       | 2012-06-21 06:00:00
3     | 4           | 1       | 2012-06-21 08:00:00
4     | 5           | 1       | 2012-06-21 01:00:00
```

what i want is create a query that "order by bought_date (desc) by category".
In that case the expected result is:

```
banana
apple
example 1
example 2
```

My query:

```
SELECT c.id, u.bought_date
    FROM categry as c
    left join product p on (c.id=p.category_id)
    left join user_list u on (p.id=u.product_id)
    WHERE u.user_id=3 
    ORDER BY u.bought_date DESC NULLS LAST
```

But this only does a simple sort by bought date...

with this result:

```
banana
example 1
apple
example 2
```

Comment: Have you tried: `ORDER BY c.id, u.bought_date DESC NULLS LAST`?

Comment: @bernie Thanks for the reply, but that example only works if the category id order corresponds to date order... The "main order" is the bought date and not the category id

Comment: Can `bought_date` be NULL? Are there FK to enforce relational integrity? Can one `product` have multiple related `user_list` entries? Why is `banana` listed before `apple`? Table definitions would clarify a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of one ordering.  You want to order by the earliest or latest date for each category.  For that, use window functions.

```
SELECT c.id, u.bought_date, max(u.bought_date) over (partition by c.id) as category_bd
FROM categry c left join
     product p
     on (c.id=p.category_id) left join
     user_list u
     on (p.id=u.product_id)
WHERE u.user_id = 3 
ORDER BY category_bd DESC NULLS LAST, u.bought_date DESC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: I aplogize for this comment, but I tried to answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323377/how-to-filter-specific-entries-from-a-mysql-table) but I can not and I am curious to see the solution. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you just need two columns in your `order by` clause:

```
SELECT c.id, u.bought_date
FROM categry as c
left join product p on (c.id=p.category_id)
left join user_list u on (p.id=u.product_id)
WHERE u.user_id=3 
ORDER BY category_id, u.bought_date DESC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that example only works if the category id order corresponds to date order... The "main order" is the bought date and not the category id

Comment: So can you clarify what result you're trying to get? Isn't it just sorting by `bought_date` and then the `category_id` (i.e., the opposite of what I've done)

Comment: Ok, so when a product is bought, all products of this category should be in the first place. Like a sort by date with a "group by category". This make sense?

Comment: OK, now I Understand. Gordon 's solution should do the trick (kudos, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming missing information:

1. `bought_date` is defined `NOT NULL`.
2. There can be multiple rows in `user_list` per product, and they can have a different `bought_date`.
3. Order products by the latest `bought_date` of their category first,
   and by their latest `bought_date` next.

```
SELECT p.product
FROM   product   p
JOIN   user_list u ON u.product_id = p.id
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY max(max(u.bought_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.category_id) DESC
        , max(u.bought_date) DESC;
```

- You don't need the table `categry` in the query at all.
- The window function to get the latest `bought_date` per category can go into the `ORDER BY` clause.
- Yes, that's a window function over the aggregate `max(u.bought_date)`.
- Obviously you don't want oranges in the result, since nobody "brought" them.
  Use `JOIN`, not <strike>`LEFT JOIN`</strike>.