# Filter students that have not passed a subject yet

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table and it has following values:

table name 'results'

```
Reg.No  SubjectCode  Attempt  Pass/Fail
112108  CMIS 1113    1        fail
112110  CMIS 1114    1        pass
112119  CMIS 1114    1        fail
112108  CMIS 1113    2        fail
112107  CMIS 1113    1        fail
112108  CMIS 1113    3        pass
```

Students can have several attempts to pass the subject.
Student should pass each subjects to get the degree.
Some student pass in first attempt.
Some take more than 3 attempt.
However student can try until he/she pass.
But some still remain fail.
So I want to get the Reg.No of students who are still unable to pass the subject.
Eg.: `112119` and `112107` are still unable to pass their subject.
I was unable to write a query for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried it at least? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: are you interested in a given subject code only or all the subjects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using aggregation:

```
SELECT `Reg.No`, SubjectCode, SUM(`Pass/Fail` = 'Pass')
FROM results
GROUP  BY `Reg.No`, SubjectCode
HAVING SUM(`Pass/Fail` = 'Pass') = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of results for each student and course where the last column is `'Pass'`.  In MySQL, booleans are treated as integers in a numeric context, with true being 1.  So, `sum(`Pass/Fail`= 'Pass')` counts the number of times a student passed the course.  The `= 0` says the student never passed the course.

As a suggestion, don't put special characters such as `/` and `.` in column names.  That requires escaping the columns and just makes the code harder to write because it is filled with backticks.

Comment: Yes Sir..I will take your advice into practice in future.Anyway your query work for me.Thank you sir for your helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery for this.

```
SELECT `Req.No`, `SubjectCode`, max(`Pass/Fail`) AS `Pass/Fail`
FROM   results
GROUP  BY 1, 2
HAVING max(`Pass/Fail`) = 'fail'
```

Assuming `Pass/Fail` is a string type, so  `'pass'` > `'fail'`.
You only get students who tried and failed, but not those who never tried (and are not in this table at all).

I really wouldn't use column name with special characters. Very error prone.

Comment: Thank you Sir..Your query work perfectly for me. Yes I am new to the SQL. Still I am learning & practicing it. Thank you for your advice too.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT Req.No FROM results WHERE `Pass/Fail` = 'fail';
```

This is pretty basic SQL. You should read some tutorials.

Edit: OK after playing around with a bit, I came to this query:

```sql
SELECT `Req.No` FROM results WHERE `Req.No` NOT IN(SELECT `Req.No` FROM results WHERE `Pass/Fail` = 'pass');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2bd80/17

Comment: This is not the query I want.This query give me Reg.No of all students who are fail.But I want to get reg.no of students still unable to pass the subject. For example 112119 still unable to pass CMIS 1114 and 112107 still unable to pass CMIS 1113.I want to filter those two only.112108 pass the subject in his 3rd attempt.So do not want his number.I want only who still unable to pass the subject.I hope you got my point.Thank you

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Please add that description to your original question.  You might need to rework your table, not sure though.

Comment: Thank you Sir,Can you suggest any modification to my table?

Comment: @Punuth this is not what you are looking for. This query displays all the `RegNO` that have failed a given exam at least once.

Comment: @Begueradj Yes Sir..That's not the one which I looking for.Do you have any solution for me?

Comment: seems like you would need some sort of subquery, but I can't figure it out, you can play with my querying code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2bd80/14

Comment: Your solution is simple and efficient. It did not come to my brain at all. Smart job. I will upvote you when I can (for the moment i can not)

Comment: @Begueradj: I don't think it's as simple and efficient as it could be.